# How can i get App Roles in an Azure Token?

Tags: azure

We are developing a react.js application that we registered in azure portal. We use the [react-microsoft-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-microsoft-login) package from npm to have the login button using our company credentials. This works well

We added App roles in the `App Registrations` page of azure, just like this :

[image]

We also assigned these roles correctly in the `Enterprise application -> Users and groups` page in Azure.

When we login using the React microsoft login button, we receive a token that contains a lot of stuff, among which the name, the mail, the job of the user. We would like to get the App role as well but we can't figure how. We read this [Add app roles to your application and receive them in the token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps) microsoft documentation but it's not too clear for me how we can actually get the user's role in the received token directly.

What is the process to follow so we get the user's app roles in the token ?

Comment: Have you tried to decode the JWT token? App roles should be under "roles" or "role".

Comment: I can't believe it was right under my nose and i didn't see it, thanks !